# PowerShell Script - ServiceURL parameter

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a powershell script to install an MSI file with a few parameters. I was told the MSI file needs the following parameters: /qn SERVICE_URL="https://.....com/InstallerServer" SSL="1"

I took a stab at it, but it failed. Can someone offer some advice?

This is what I tried:

```
Execute-MSI -Action Install –Path 'InstallerService.msi'-Parameters "/QN /SERVICE_URL=https://…..com/InstallerServer /SSL=1"
```

Comment: What is Execute-MSI? What code is it running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `$Installer` takes the full path to the msi and `$Arguments` - well - your arguments

```
$Installer = 'C:\install\InstallerService.msi'
$Arguments = '/qn SERVICE_URL="https://.....com/InstallerServer" SSL="1"'
Start-Process -FilePath $Installer -ArgumentList $Arguments
```

you could add the switch `-Wait` to not just start the process but wait until it's completed (if you want to perform further actions after its execution) like so:

```
Start-Process -FilePath $Installer -ArgumentList $Arguments -Wait
```